# Behavior of class variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class, oop

```
>>> class a:
...     b=5
...     def __init__(self,x,y):
...             self.x=x
...             self.y=y
...
>>> p=a(5,6)
>>> q=a(5,6)
>>> a.b
5
>>> a.b+=1
>>> p.b
6
>>> q.b
6
>>> q.b-=1
>>> q.b
5
>>> p.b
6
>>> a.b
6
```

As you see, on changing the **class variable** by an instance's method, the same doesn't gets reflected in the class variable and the class variable of other instance. Why is it so?

Comment: You can read a class attribute from the instance, but as soon as you set an instance attribute with the same name, it is shadowed. `+=` and `-=` do that.

Answer (score 6):

Because `q.b -= 1` creates an instance variable with the name `b`, look in your `__dict__`:

```
q.__dict__
{'b': 4, 'x': 5, 'y': 6}

p.__dict__
{'x': 5, 'y': 6}
```

`q.b` is different than `a.b`, you've shadowed `a.b` after the assignment. Take note that this isn't a Python 3 specific issue, Python 2 also behaves in the same way.

This is clearly stated in the [assignment statement section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) of the Language Reference:

> Note: If the object is a class instance and the attribute reference occurs on both sides of the assignment operator, the RHS expression, `a.x` can access either an instance attribute or (if no instance attribute exists) a class attribute. The LHS target `a.x` is always set as an instance attribute, creating it if necessary. Thus, the two occurrences of `a.x` do not necessarily refer to the same attribute: if the RHS expression refers to a class attribute, the LHS creates a new instance attribute as the target of the assignment:
>
> ```
> class Cls:
>     x = 3             # class variable
> inst = Cls()
> inst.x = inst.x + 1   # writes inst.x as 4 leaving Cls.x as 3
> ```
>
> This description does not necessarily apply to descriptor attributes, such as properties created with `property()`.